# Negate $\not\exists\epsilon>0: \forall\delta> 0: \not\exists x \in \{x:|x - x_0| < \delta\} : |x^2_0 - x^2| > \epsilon $

Tags: logic

Negate the following statement, 
$$\not\exists\epsilon>0: \forall\delta> 0: \not\exists x \in \{x:|x - x_0| < \delta\} : |x^2_0 - x^2| > \epsilon $$

My working,

$$\iff\neg (\not\exists\epsilon>0: \forall\delta> 0: \not\exists x \in \{x:|x - x_0| < \delta\} : |x^2_0 - x^2| > \epsilon )$$

$$\iff\neg (\exists\epsilon>0): \neg (\forall\delta> 0): \neg (\not\exists x \in \{x:|x - x_0| < \delta\}) : \neg (|x^2_0 - x^2| > \epsilon ))$$

$$\iff\forall\epsilon>0: \exists\delta> 0: \exists x \in \{x:|x - x_0| < \delta\} : |x^2_0 - x^2| \leq \epsilon $$

However, on the solutions provided it says that last line is,

$$\forall\epsilon>0: \exists\delta> 0: \exists x \in \{x:|x - x_0| < \delta\} : |x^2_0 - x^2| > \epsilon $$

Which is correct; the provided solution, or mine? If it's the former, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided solution is correct.

Think about it like this:

If statement $p$ says, "There is no $x $ such that certain conditions hold", then the negation of $p$ is, "There $\it{is}$ an $x$ such that those same conditions hold";  not "There is an $x$ such that those conditions $\it{don't}$ hold."

Your exercise asks for the negation of the statement:

$$\exists \epsilon \:  \forall \delta \: p $$

which is:

$$ \forall \epsilon\: \exists \delta  \: \neg p $$

for the above $p $.